# Strange Disapearing elements in small browsers when hover

Tags: css, media-queries

Hi There when I make my browser smaller than 420px (Using Chrome Stable) the Navigation elements in the first navigation line disapear, when I hover them. I cannot find the mistake.

Can anybody help? Website is: http://www.tokemedia.de

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to style.css and change display:inline to inline-block;

```
#navi ul li {
float: left;
margin-left: 10px;
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;/* not inline*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped! Why exactly does that need to be inline-block instead of inline?

Comment: An inline element has no line break before or after it, and it tolerates HTML elements next to it.

A block element has some whitespace above and below it and does not tolerate any HTML elements next to it.

An inline-block element is placed as an inline element (on the same line as adjacent content), but it behaves as a block element.  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp